# Excel VBA: reference to prev Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, date

i'm trying to dynamically refernece to a cell in the Sheet to the left. FOr this i wrote this function

```
Function PrevSheet(RCell As Range)
    Dim xIndex As Long
    Application.Volatile
    xIndex = RCell.Worksheet.Index
    If xIndex > 1 Then _
        PrevSheet = Worksheets(xIndex - 1).Range(RCell.Address)
End Function
```

In most cases it works fine, but if the referenced cell has a date like 25.06.2018 in it, then i get a wrong date(in this case 26.06.2022).
That occurs only if i set the option to use 1904 date formats, but i need this option for negative time formats.
Of course, there is an obvious workaround: i can just substract 1462 from the result, but is there a neater way to solve that?

Comment: I don't get your question. What does date have to do with your Worksheet index reference?

Comment: I think you need to change the question title - it's not about referencing the previous sheet (which works) it's how to handle the 1904 date system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Value2 property of Range, i.e.

```
PrevSheet = Worksheets(xIndex - 1).Range(RCell.Address).Value2
```

Comment: ok, that's interesting.... was halfway into a whole comment about how the underlying number for the date isn't changing when the date system changes and you come along and s**t out `Value2` which works.  So `Value2` doesn't handle dates or currency and converts them to a floating point number instead... and not sure after that.  :)